# Is there an app that can send yourself notifications regularly?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, notifications

Is there an app that can send yourself custom notifications regularly?

For example: I want to have my phone send me a notification every day at noon to “Drink water”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Native Calendar app
- Native Reminders app in iOS 14+
- https://apps.apple.com/app/unotifs-custom-notifications/id1400535863
- https://apps.apple.com/app/reminder-with-voice-reminders/id469454389